# If $G$ is a locally compact Hausdorff group, when does $G/Z$ have a probability Haar measure?

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups

I am reading an introductory material about topological groups and the question
in the tittle comes up. Due this Proposition

**Proposition. A locally compact Hausdorff topological group $G$ is compact, if and only if, $\mu(G)<+\infty\qquad $ ($\mu$ is the Haar measure of $G$).**

it is enough to know what are the groups $G$ for which $G/Z$, where $Z$ is the center of $G$, is a compact group. Are those groups well-known ?

Comment: You are asking about the classification up to isomorphism of (topological) central extensions $0\to A\to G\to K\to1$ with $A$ locally compact abelian and $K$ compact. These extensions with $K$ and $A$ fixed are classified by the second continuous cohomology group $H_{c}^2(K,A)$. Phrasing it this way it is rather clear that full answer is rather impossible. For specific (nice) groups $K$ (e.g. semi-simple Lie) and $A$ not too bad (e.g. $\mathbb{R,Z,R/Z}$ and finite products thereof) the answer should be known but I don't have the relevant texts (Guichardet, Borel-Wallach) handy at the moment.

Comment: In my first sentence I was a bit ambiguous. I meant: you are asking in particular about the classification up to isomorphism of all $G$ arising as such topological central extensions.

Comment: Hi Theo, thanks for all the informations. It is simple to give an example where $G/Z$ is not compact ?

Comment: Hi Leandro This should be a comment rather than an answer, but I can't currently login from this computer. A very simple example of a non-compact quotient group is $PSL_2 (\mathbb{R}) = SL_2 (\mathbb{R})/\{\pm 1\}$ where $\pm 1$ is the center of $ SL_2 (\mathbb{R})$ consisting of $\pm$ the identity matrix. More generally, if $G$ is a non-compact [semi-simple linear Lie group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-simple_Lie_group) then $G/Z(G)$ will be non-compact. I hope this answers your follow-up question. Theo

Comment: Hi Theo, thanks a lot. I first thought about some matriz groups but I wrong convinced myself that they were compacts. The collection of example you provided let more clear that is in pratical very hard to classify all the groups with that property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $G$ discrete, it is a well-known theorem of Schur that those $G$ such that $G/Z(G)$ is finite are finite-by-abelian, i.e., their derived subgroup is finite. See [this survey](http://ijgt.ui.ac.ir/article_7376.html) by Dixon, Kurdachenko, and Pypka.

The locally compact version also holds. Namely, if $G$ is locally compact and $G/Z(G)$ is compact, then $\overline{[G,G]}$ is compact. Indeed, the assumption that $G/Z(G)$ is compact implies that all conjugacy classes in $G$ have compact closure. This implies, by a [result of T.S. Wu and Y.K. Yu](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1029000939) (Michigan Math. J, 1972) that the closure $\overline{[G,G]}$ the derived subgroup of $G$ is a locally elliptic group, in the sense that every compact subset is contained in a compact subgroup. This applies to the set of commutators in $G$, which is compact (because the commutator map $G^2\to G$ factors through $(G/Z)^2$), and therefore $\overline{[G,G]}$ is compact.

Comment: (The argument also shows that if the set of commutators of a locally compact group $G$ has compact closure, then so does the derived subgroup.)